# Use an image for a menu option in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use the following XAML to achieve a menu using radio buttons:

```
        <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>


        <StackPanel Margin="25,74,644,78" Background="{x:Null}">
        <RadioButton Content="1. Do something." Click="RadioButton1_Click" FontSize="16" Margin="5"/>
        <RadioButton Content="2. Do something else." Click="RadioButton2_Click" FontSize="16" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This works fine but I want to include an image as a menu option instead of text. (The image is for 'Home' and it will have a normal image and a hover over image)

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define another style for displaying Radio Button as an Image based on the existing style posted in question, just need slight changes in ControlTemplate's content part. Following is an example of such a Style and the usage :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PictSTyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Image Width="50" Height="50">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="home_default.png" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="home_hovered.png" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PictSTyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a menu item an image:

```
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source=""/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
```

for your trigger just change the MenuItem's icon to the "highlighted one", when the user hovers over the menu item (IsMouseOver), by changing the Icon's image source.

Comment: But I want to use the RadioButton method so when the user clicks one menu item the others get 'unclicked' and therefore change color. I cant do this with the MenuItem method

Comment: Are you making a tabbed UI? Just trying to understand what you're doing.

Comment: Its a MainWindow that has a menu in the image I posted above.  WHen the user clicks a menu item it highlights and displays a WPF page and the rest of the menu items are 'un-highlighted'

Answer (score 0):

Put an image element as the "Content" property for your radio button

```
<RadioButton Click=HomRadioButtonClick>
   <RadioButton.Content>
      <Image Source=""/>
   </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

You'll need some extra logic for the hover behavior, but that should at least get the image in your menu.